# "svhost(netsvc)" is using about 40-80% CPU when the system starts

Tags: windows-7, services, cpu-usage, cpu-speed

My CPU usage is constantly at 40% (maximum 95%) most of the time when I start my PC. It continues to work at this rate for about 15-25 minutes.

I checked the performance monitor and found out that there is a service "svhost(netsvc)" which consumes all the CPU. When I suspend it, the system becomes unresponsive.

What can I do? All the other tasks like Windows Media Player etc. become slower, and I even experience audio corruption due to this heavy system usage.

I'm using Windows 7 64bit on 4GB RAM and an Intel Core 2 Quad 8200 CPU, with a DG41TY motherboard.

Comment: svChost is system service and running with multiply invocations usually (it's "Generic Host Process for Win32 Services")

Answer (score 0):

Netsvc (*original*) is remote control of a service (from you to another host), you can decide, have you use it at all?

AFAIK Netsvc is not a part of Win7 distro, why and when you had it is question to you